# How do i rotate set of models that make a bigger model(a car) to 0°?

Tags: modeling, objects

How do i rotate a set of models(created from main model, i call them submodels, the project i am working on is a car mod for a computer game(Beamng [Link for forum post][1],

Basically i imported the model from a website(after i got permission from the site, provided i dont make any profit for the end project and it will be avaible for everyone(everyone who owns the game legally atleast)

When i imported the model, it got rotated 0.6 something degrees in W/E directions, how do i rotate whole model to 0 degrees(as it should be)?

I know i could like join the submodels(set of models making a car body, eg chassis, doors, bonnet, lights, glasses) whit ctrl+J, but that might/will break my UV maps and all the job i have done on it....

These are the files of the model i have right now, part of the original problem was fixed(model rotation, but axis rotation still remains)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6vRqq08Rx2JeTdqYzRicGJaMDA/view

https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/bd2528331b1fea82a6d84998460b89e4997fa0b9317a0a39fabbc5497a21efe0/analysis/1500458932/

Comment: was this rotation done in edit mode or object mode?

Comment: I did found a partial fix on reddt blender subreddit (shift+a in object mode, then click on rotate) that changed all models rotation to 0° whitout moving the objects from eachother(the car and its parts stayed relative wise the same). However the translation Axis(blue, green and red) is still at 2° angle or so, any idea how to fix it?

Comment: There is something haunted going on there in your .blend file.  The objects are not behaving the way I expect them to when I use the rotation operator, they just wiggle around locationwise and do not actually rotate at all.

Comment: I wonder if it is the "Manipulate Center Points" toggle as described in https://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=27560

Comment: I have gotten the issue resolved(forgot to close it here.... The problem of posting the same problem in multiple different media sources....) https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/6o2ku0/how_do_i_rotate_multiple_models_at_onceeg_models/

Comment: Basically i got the original model(I based my work on, after getting permission from website administrators) from :http://animium.com/2013/05/zaz-968-3d-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select several objects and begin a rotation using the <kbd>r</kbd> key they will rotate as a unit, preserving relative position and orientation (unless pivoting around Individual Origins).

If the pivot point that blender picks (default is median) is not to your liking, you can change the pivot point to something like Cursor or maybe Active Element.  The 3D Cursor can be set to any coordinate using the <kbd>n</kbd> sidebar.

Comment: Part of the problem was fixed, I got help from reddit blender subreddit for model rotation(shift+a in object mode, choose rotate), but axis rotation still remains 2 degrees or so to the right... Any idea for fix? added link for the file and virustotal report at body of the question!